# How do I create a vector that is the sum of the last 12 months' values in a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, economics

So, I have a two time-series with a monthly frequency. Monthly Brazilian federal government revenue ("receitamensal" vector) and monthly spending ("gastomensal" vector). I want to create two vectors out of those series: accumulated revenue in the last 12 months and accumulated spending in the last 12 months. So that in any given month, the value is the sum of the last 12 months. 
I'm using the BETS library to get my data. Right now my code is:

```
library(BETS) 
Receitamensal <- BETS.deflate(BETS.get(7544),
                          BETS.GET(433),
                            type='perc')
Gastomensal <- BETS.deflate(BETS.get(7546),
                        BETS.GET(433),
                          type='perc')
```

So, what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow that package had a lot of dependencies to install.
Does the following work for you?

```
tail(Receitamensal,12)
tail(Gastomensal, 12)
```

And then simply put `sum()` around each one.

**EDIT:**

If you are looking for a rolling sum as indicated in the comments, then you will find the `rollsum()` function from the `zoo` package (thank you @ulfelder) the most useful:

```
install.packages("zoo")
zoo::rollsum(Receitamensal, 12, fill = NA, align = "right")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of new to R. How should I combine the `sum` and `tail` functions?

Comment: `sum(tail(Receitamensal, 12))`

Comment: And that code will provide an output so that in any given month, the value is the sum of the last 12 months?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by any given month. How are you selecting your month? tail simple reads the end of the object - or in this case, the time series object. No matter what `Receitamensal` ends on, `tail(Receitamensal,12)` will show the last 12 values in `Receitamensal`.

Comment: Imagine a moving average, I'm trying to get "moving sum". So that, let's say, my new vector's value on march 2002 is the result of the sums of the observations I have in `Receitamensal` from march 2001 to march 2002.

Comment: So perhaps you should `install.packages("xts")` and use the `xts::rollsum(Receitamensal, 12, fill = NA, align = "right")` instead?

Comment: The `rollapply` family is part of `zoo`, on which `xts` depends. So unless you need something specific in `xts`, it may be simpler to do `zoo::rollsum`.

Comment: @PedroCavalcanteOliveira if the proposed solution works for you please let me know and accept this as the answer to your question.